Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in Unity
I'm building the project to Nintendo Switch platform in Unity 2023.2.15.f1.
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\AppPkg\6w12j\main.npdm failed with output:
The system cannot find the path specified.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 4 seconds (4419 ms)
Building Library\Bee\artifacts\AppPkg\6w12j\main.npdm failed with output:
The system cannot find the path specified.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)


Build failed



make sure you turn off your antivirus for that area - but other than that, if you're a nintendo compiler, you have a direct contact at unity, they could be your best contact

Try these steps:

close the editor, delete the Library folder, and then reopen it, This takes some time to re-create the library and then try building the scene.

if this doesn't work:

look at the top bar and click on Assets > Reimport all, this will start loading and will reimport everything then try building the scene

if this doesn't work

look at the top bar and click Assets > Export Package, this will create a .unitypackage file.

Now, Go to Unity Hub create a new project, go to Assets > import package > custom package, and select the .unitypackage we exported before, it will start importing it after that build the scene
if still it doesn't work let me know what packages you have imported, any of the package will be creating the issue.
